# Image in 3D animation is not appearing in render

Tags: rendering, image

I'm a total beginner.  I've created a simple animation consisting of a rotating image.  It looks fine from the Camera Perspective.  I've placed the lighting and camera appropriately.  But when I render the animation I'm getting a black screen.

I slapped a meatball object into the animation and it renders fine.  I'm suspecting that images are somehow unsupported unless they're attached to an object.  Is this true?

The program allows me to add an image to the animation workspace and manipulate its parameters.  It seems like a cruel joke not to render the image.   Or is there some magic attribute I need to set deep in the image or elsewhere to get it to render?

I've checked the Compositing and all of the usual suspects (as per many Google searches) for black images.

Any insight would be appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_CEsPD_OlE

This video should show you how to do it, hope it helps

Comment: because that is just an "Empty" object. it's not designed to be rendered. use a proper mesh object like a plane or circle and add a material to it. You can also use the addon *Images as Planes* https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/images_as_planes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images are not unsupported. I tested your file, so I imported the image as background, then as reference and lastly as "Image as planes". The last one was the only time that it rendered as it had material as image and Principled BSDF material applied. Now I think that you imported the image as either Background or Reference and applied animation on it. Try it with Images as Planes, maybe that will work.

Comment: Thanks to Nascent Space, Harry McKenzie, and Wiseman for the quick and clear responses.  The "Images as Planes" add-on solved the problem.

Comment: Not much to test there in the file... the object is an empty, empties won't get rendered.